# SNMP4J snmp4android.jar android

Tags: android, snmp

This sample SNMP4J code is using the ported snmp4android.jar

Thank you for all the help thus far....

Not working error states deprecation?  --> snmp.sendPDU(pdu, target, null, listener);

Any help would be appreciated, I am sure these are basic Java questions.

Kind Regards,

~ Mike

```
package snmpman.xxxxxx.com;

import org.snmp4j.CommunityTarget;
import org.snmp4j.PDU;
import org.snmp4j.Snmp;
import org.snmp4j.event.ResponseEvent;
import org.snmp4j.event.ResponseListener;
import org.snmp4j.mp.SnmpConstants;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OID;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OctetString;
import org.snmp4j.smi.UdpAddress;
import org.snmp4j.smi.VariableBinding;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DroidActivity extends Activity {

private Snmp snmp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toast.makeText(DroidActivity.this, "Start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Create Target
        UdpAddress targetAddress = new UdpAddress("192.168.1.50/161");
        CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
        target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
        target.setAddress(targetAddress);
        target.setRetries(2);
        target.setTimeout(1500);
        target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version1);

        // creating PDU
        PDU pdu = new PDU();
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(new int[] {1,3,6,1,2,1,1,1})));
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(new int[] {1,3,6,1,2,1,1,2})));
        pdu.setType(PDU.GETNEXT);

        // sending request
   ResponseListener listener = new ResponseListener() {
       public void onResponse(ResponseEvent event) {

            ((Snmp)event.getSource()).cancel(event.getRequest(), this);
    Toast.makeText(DroidActivity.this, "Received response PDU is: "+event.getResponse(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
       };




    **snmp.sendPDU(pdu, target, null, listener);**



       Toast.makeText(DroidActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}       

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
UdpAddress targetAddress = new UdpAddress("127.0.0.1/1985");
CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();

//...Whatever

target.setAddress(targetAddress);
```